# Disable jQuery Draggable after keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2vtDj/1/

Right now the boxes are draggable, but I want them to be UNdraggable after text is entered into the input box.

jQuery I've been messing with:

```
    // tried 'disable', and just #sortable without li
    $("#sortable > li").draggable('destroy');
```

Full code:

```
    $('input').keyup(function() {
filter(this);

});

function filter(element) {
var value = $(element).val();

$("#sortable > li").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) {
        $(this).show();
        $(".number").show();
        $(".numberstwo").show();
         $("#sortable > li").draggable('destroy');     

        // $('#sortable').addClass("destory");


    } else {
        $(this).hide();
        $(".number").hide();
        $(".numberstwo").hide();
        $(".games").css( "padding-top", "40px"); 

    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true,
    placeholder: "dashed-placeholder"  ,
    cancel: '.canceled' // <-----add this option
});
```

and

```
$("#sortable > li").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1) {
        $(this).show();
        $(".number").fadeOut();
        $(".numberstwo").fadeOut();
        $(this).addClass('canceled'); // <---- add
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
        $(".number").show();
        $(".numberstwo").show();         
        $(this).removeClass('canceled');  // <---- add
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm. Not working for me locally or in jsfiddle.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @edawg - 'Sortable' Do you maintain?

Comment: Yes, that works! But with the keyup, it does not go back into place.  I'll keep working with it, thank you.